# Wordpress Magic Fields if content

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a magic fields plugin image code that will check to see if there is an image, and if so wrap the image in a div, if not, dont include the text. Any ideas? this is what I have so far but isnt working.

```
<?php if ( get_image('main_image',TRUE) ) {
'<div id="slideshow">'
echo get_image('main_image'); 
 '</div>'
} else {

} ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP syntax is wrong. You're mixing PHP and HTML together. Try this:

```
<?php if ( get_image('main_image',TRUE) ) { ?>
    <div id="slideshow">
        <?php echo get_image('main_image'); ?>
    </div>
<?php } else {

} ?>
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much, I had a mental block. Must have tried loads of variations and it was staring me in the face! thanks